# Angular 4: using component variables inside custom validator functions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, form-control

```
ngOnInit(): void {

this.formBuilder.group({
          nameFormCtrl: ['', this.validateName],
          });

}

validateName(c: FormControl) {
    return c.value === this.name ? null : {
      validateName: {
        valid: false
      }
    };
  }
```

Here `this.name` should refer to the component, instead, it refers to undefined

Comment: May I know where have you initialized the "this.name"?

Comment: in the component constructor

Comment: use this ----> nameFormCtrl: ['', this.validateName.bind(this)]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Class methods do not have `this` bound to the current instance, they are dependent on the caller to pass the appropriate `this` to the function when calling, just like any other `function` in Javascript

You can use an arrow function which captures `this` from declaration context, or explicitly bind `this` using `bind`:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
      nameFormCtrl: ['', c=> this.validateName(c)],
      // OR
      nameFormCtrl: ['', this.validateName.bind(this)],
});
```

Comment: what if my control is declared like this: this.form.setControl('nameFormCtrl', form);